# In a single csv file, compare two lines for equality

Tags: java, file, csv

I have a single CSV file which contains many lines.

1shelf CSV file sample content:

```
#ManagementNode,SHELF-INFORMATION,NE_ID,RACK_ID,SHLEF_ID,STATUS,SHELF_TYPE,MAX_SLOT_NUMBER
ManagementNode,SHELF-INFORMATION,0005,0,0,,,13
#ManagementNode,BOARD-INFORMATION,NE_ID,RACK_ID,SHELF_ID,SLOT_ID,BOARD_NAME,ACTIVE_MODE,ADMIN_STATE,OPER_STATE,VERSION,SERIAL_NO,MANUFACTURER,MANUFACTURE_DATE
ManagementNode,BOARD-INFORMATION,0005,0,0,6,LEMA0,ACTIVE,UNLOCK,ENABLE,,S61F91571,XYZ,2014-09-03
```

2shelf CSV file sample content:

```
#ManagementNode,SHELF-INFORMATION,NE_ID,RACK_ID,SHLEF_ID,STATUS,SHELF_TYPE,MAX_SLOT_NUMBER
ManagementNode,SHELF-INFORMATION,0001,0,0,,,13
#ManagementNode,SHELF-INFORMATION,NE_ID,RACK_ID,SHLEF_ID,STATUS,SHELF_TYPE,MAX_SLOT_NUMBER
ManagementNode,SHELF-INFORMATION,0001,0,1,,,13
```

Please note that in the 2shelf file the header value of line 1 and line 3 is the same and also line 2 5th row value is 0 and line 5 5th row value is 1, this means it's a 2shelf file. The same is not true for 1shelf file.

I am new to Java, able to print required lines but dont know how to implement the compare logic to figure out 1shelf or 2shelf file.

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("C:\\Files\\1_2_Shelf\\Test.csv"));
        String info = "";
            int startLine = 4;
            int endLine = 7;
            for (int i = 0; i < startLine; i++) { 
                info = in.readLine();
                }
            for (int i = startLine; i < endLine + 1; i++) {
                info = in.readLine();
                System.out.println(info);
            }

            in.close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the `import` shown below to the top of your class file.

Then use `info.split(",")` to break up the CSV string into fields in an array.

Then you will grab the 5th field of the array using field index = 4 (array element indexes starts at zero).

Sample code below, inserted into your original code:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;    // NEW import to add at top of your file
...

// Some constants for identifying shelves
final int FIELD_SHELF_ID = 4;
final String SHELF1 = "0";
final String SHELF2 = "1";

BufferedReader in = 
    new BufferedReader (new FileReader("C:\\Files\\1_2_Shelf\\Test.csv"));
String info = "";
int startLine = 4;
int endLine = 7;
for (int i = 0; i < startLine; i++) {
    info = in.readLine();
}
for (int i = startLine; i < endLine + 1; i++) {
    info = in.readLine();
    System.out.println(info);

    String infoFields[] = info.split(",");
    System.out.println("infoFields[FIELD_SHELF_ID] = 
        " + infoFields[FIELD_SHELF_ID]);

    switch(infoFields[FIELD_SHELF_ID]) {
        case SHELF1:
            System.out.println("Found 1SHELF row"); break;
        case SHELF2:
            System.out.println("Found 2SHELF row"); break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Unknown shelf-type row"); break;
    }
}

in.close();
```

If you are using an older version of Java, instead of the `switch` statement you can use `if/else if/else` as follows:

```
if (infoFields[FIELD_SHELF_ID].equals(SHELF1)) {
    System.out.println("Found 1SHELF row");
}
else if (infoFields[FIELD_SHELF_ID].equals(SHELF2)) {
    System.out.println("Found 2SHELF row");
}
else {
    System.out.println("Unknown shelf-type row");
}
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply and really appreciate quick response.
I am using jdk1.6.32  and for switch stmt IDE is asking me to use jdk1.7 (Cannot switch on a value of type String for source level below 1.7. Only convertible int values or enum variables are permitted) which i cannot as current deployed code is on 1.6

Comment: I added some code to the end of my answer that will help you avoid the `switch` statement.

Comment: Please use a CSV parser / reader instead of just jumping at commas.